# Photoshop scripting move one group inside of other

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to move one LayerSet into the other LayerSet in PhotoShop scripting. Here's my code:

```
// Source
var srcGroup = app.activeDocument.layerSets.add();
srcGroup.name = 'source';

// Target
var targetGroup = app.activeDocument.layerSets.add();
targetGroup.name = 'target';

srcGroup.move(targetGroup, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
```

This gives an error "Error 1220: Illegal Argument". If I change the second argument to `ElementPlacement.PLACEAFTER`, it the error is gone but it is not quite doing what I want.

Answer (score 3):

As you found out not all values of `ElementPlacement` are valid for all object types. I decided to make a workarround by adding a dummieGroup and place the source before the dummy. At the end the dummy will be removed.

```
var srcGroup = app.activeDocument.layerSets.add();
srcGroup.name = "source";
var targetGroup = app.activeDocument.layerSets.add();
targetGroup.name = "target";

//adding the dummy INSIDE the target LayerSet
var dummieGroup = targetGroup.layerSets.add();
dummieGroup.name = "dummy";

srcGroup.move(dummieGroup, ElementPlacement.PLACEBEFORE);
dummieGroup.remove();
```

To remove a `layerSet` it have to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (targetGroup.layers.length > 0){
    srcGroup.move(targetGroup.layers[targetGroup.layers.length-1], ElementPlacement.PLACEAFTER);
} else {
    srcGroup.move(targetGroup, ElementPlacement.PLACEAFTER);
}
```